# Parcel is not creating a dist folder when I use build command

Tags: bundler, tailwind-css, parceljs

I got stuck while building a site using Tailwind CSS and Parcel as a bundler. When I use the `npm start` command, it creates a `dist` folder and server it on localhost, port:1234. But when I use the `npm build` command, it does not create a `dist` folder and build in the root folder instead. By the way, I got to know about the commands from [here](https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/). Here's my `package.json`.

```json
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Empty project.",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel serve ./src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/index.html"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Surayani02/my-website.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Surayani02/my-website/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Surayani02/my-website#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-beta.3.1",
    "postcss": "^8.2.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"build:prod": "parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist"

try this command

replce "main" with "default"
"default": "index.html",

then try it works

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using -d flag, not --dist-dir in parcel@2.4.1.

```
parcel build src/index.html -d output
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be the source of the problem -dist-dir is a valid cli flag in current versions of parcel https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters

Comment: Yes, I'm just sharing what works for me, maybe it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling "autoprefixer" and "postcss" packages, because I believe they are already included in ParcelJS.

Then try to run "parcel ./src/index.html" in your console, to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me before installing webview2 runtime. https://developer.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: This does not look like an answer. Do you suggest the poster to install the WebView2 runtime? Clarify it a little, please.